# How to HTML, jQuery, numbers API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

So, I'm using Brackets and I keep running into this issue, maybe I just don't understand these things enough. Here's what I want to do, I'm trying to make an HTML document that has an input field and button. When you enter a number in the input field and press the button, it gives that information to a separate `app.js` file that connects with an api and finds an interesting fact about the number. The issue I'm running into is, I can't seem to connect the html with the JavaScript/jQuery.

Please help, thanks in advance.

```js
$(function Test(){
  $("#button").click( function() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    alert('button clicked');
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://numbersapi.com/" + userInput + "/math?callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {
      var hi = results;
      console.log(hi);
      $("#results").append(results + "hi");
    }
  });
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Pick a number</h1>
<input type="text" id="userInput">Number</input><br>
<button onclick="">Submit</button>
<p id="results">This is a paragraph!</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1- Syntax errors. Extra } after the alert.

2- Wrong CSS selector is being used to bind the function. No ID attribute in the button html.

3- You are including two jQuery script. You should remove one. (Thanks @Nishit Maheta for pointing this out)

All fixes:

```js
$(function Test(){
  $("#button-sbm").click(function() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    alert('button clicked');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://numbersapi.com/" + userInput + "/math?callback=?",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(results) {
        var hi = results;
        console.log(hi);
        $("#results").append(results + "hi");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Pick a number</h1>
<input type="text" id="userInput">Number</input><br>
<button id="button-sbm" onclick="">Submit</button>
<p id="results">This is a paragraph!</p>
```

Check out code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3u20mjo/)